# How to play a youtube video without iframes?

Tags: html, css, mobile, video

Looking for a way to display a youtube video in a video player powered by HTML, Javascript, PHP, or CSS. Probably CSS. I'm not against downloading the video and hosting it myself it need be but I would prefer to let google host it.

Any Ideas?

Comment: http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171780

Answer (score 2):

When you embed a video, you have the option to use the "Old Embed Code", which uses an object tag rather than an iframe. Here is an example:

```html
<object width="560" height="315">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/aBcDeFg?hl=en_US&amp;version=3"></param>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/aBcDeFg?hl=en_US&amp;version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

An even better way: Use Yahoo Media Player!
Just include this code on the body of your page:
 `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://webplayer.yahooapis.com/player.js"> </script>`
Just add a link to a youtube video on the body of your page. Then, when it is clicked it will play! Also, if you add more than one video/audio file then it will have all those in a playlist. More information here: http://webplayer.yahoo.com/ or more code, and a demo here: http://webplayer.yahoo.com/get/
Shadowpat

Comment: This is a pretty cool script thank you for sharing it. However I need the video to be displayed like it would be an iframe, but without an iframe. Iframes don't work well with mobile sites.

Comment: ohh i see what you mean. Yeah, Yahoo Player may be a bit weird on a mobile site. I'm guessing the reason you didn't want to use iframes was because they may not be displayed properly, or even supported, on mobile devices. Maybe there is a plugin to do this?

Comment: These links are 404'ing... where's the source?

Comment: Those links are no longer valid.

Answer (score -1):

As of later than January 27, 2015: Use the API as object code has been deprecated:

> March 9, 2015
>
> The document has been updated to reflect the fact that YouTube  embeds, the YouTube Flash Player API and the YouTube JavaScript Player API have all been deprecated as of January 27, 2015. A deprecation warning appears in several sections of this document to help point readers to the IFrame Player API as an alternative.

The API code can look something like:

```
<div id="ytplayer"></div>

<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
    });
  }
</script>
```

Both quote and code sourced from: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

In looking at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

The source of the page shows that the API emits the player as html, with a video tag for the actual video display:

```
<div id="player" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
 <div class="html5-video-player unstarted-mode ytp-hide-controls" tabindex="-1" id="player_uid_7211231_1" data-version="/yts/jsbin/player-vflC8Yy7I/en_US/base.js" aria-label="YouTube Video Player">
      <div class="html5-video-container" data-layer="0">
           <video tabindex="-1" class="video-stream html5-main-video" controlslist="nodownload" style="width: 720px; height: 405px; left: 0px; top: -405px;"></video>
      </div>
      <div class="ytp-gradient-top" data-layer="1"></div>
      ...
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it now converts into an iframe